# Java: Is a reflection called the same every time on every machine?

Tags: java, reflection, network-programming

This is an odd question. I have a method that populates a list with a collection of classes using java reflection.

```
    import org.reflections.Reflections;
    ...
    Reflections reflections = new Reflections("network.packet");
    Class<?>[] packets = new Class<?>[256];
    for (Class<?> c : reflections.getSubTypesOf(Packet.class))
    {
        try {
            byte opcode = ((Packet)c.newInstance()).getOpcode();
            packets[opcode] = c;
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

GetOpcode returns a byte registering a byte to a packet. I'm wondering if i can make my code more API friendly, by offering a automatic solution to opcode mapping. Currently I have in the Classes that extend Packet force a call the super constructor with a byte registering an opcode.

```
setOpcode(byte num)
```

that sets an opcode for this class.

My problem lyes in whether or not I can trust org.reflection to run the same way every-time on every machine to calculate the codes rather then having them hard coded, and making users of the API not step on already existing codes.

So, does anyone know?

Comment: @mjn reflections-0.9.10

Answer (score 1):

org.reflections isn't calculating the codes - you're just using it to iterate over the subtypes of `Packet` which provide a code.

As long as all your `Packet` extensions are on the class path (and they all provide a unique code that will fit in that array) then you're fine.

As for a "better way" - you could consider a "registration" mechanism (ie: *push* the Packet classes into a registry) instead of the "discovery" mechanism (ie: *pull* the Packet classes from the class path) you're using now - whether it's better depends on your end use case though.

Comment: I know its not calculating, what I'm saying is when I do the reflection to get all of the classes in the same namespace. Wether or not it does it the same each time. EX: I get packet1, packet2, packet3. if i move to another machine it might load differently and return packet2, packet1, packet3.

Comment: I would be very suspicious of depending on that behavior even for one machine.

Comment: Oh the classes can absolutely come in any order (they can even be loaded in a different order, and are typically stored internally by the class loader in a HashMap, which does not guarantee order). __You should not depend on class loading order, ever__. Your code shows using opcode as an index to the array though, so it handles out of order results already..